# Which of the following would be least performance draining when sorting large amounts of data?

Tags: sql, yii2

First way using the `sort` option from ActiveDataProvider in the controller.

```
public function prepareDataProvider()
{
    $query = $this->setupQueryWithPermissions();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'id' => SORT_DESC,
            ]
        ],
    ]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Or the following in the model:

```
 public static function find()
{
    $query = new CallQuery(get_called_class());
    $query->leftJoin('call_rec_files', 'calls.callref = call_rec_files.callref')
        ->select('calls.*, call_rec_files.crfref as callrecord_id')
        ->orderBy(['calls.callref' => SORT_DESC]);

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: this looks more like a code review question

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam is there somewhere I could post it to get a decent answer?

Comment: for a decent answer you should go to yiiframework forum they can provide you better insights or you have the codereview option also